# 'this' refers to wrong dynamically generated element in jQuery on()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

As part of a dynamic form I have a checkbox field that enables and disables the next input field (they are a pair, so when you add a new section to the form, the checkbox and the input field are both added together).

```
.form-element
  .checkbox
    = f.label :foo_bool_field do
      = f.check_box :foo_bool_field, class: 'foo-bool-field-form-toggle'
      .desc_foo_bool_field= "text describing field"

  .input
    = f.label :bar_input_field
    = f.text_field :bar_input_field, disabled: f.object.foo_bool_field
```

and it's all in a `.form` class block.

Here is the code that does the disabling

```
$('.form').on('change', '.foo-bool-field-form-toggle', function(e) {
  // disabling code goes here
});
```

If I add a few of these form elements, then click on the text "text describing foo_bool_field", it enables/disables the input form of the first set only. If I throw a debugger above the form disabling code and check `this`, the `this` always returns the first set. If I click the actually text box □, it works properly, disabling the check boxes and referring to the right `this` of the checkbox that I actually clicked on.

Any ideas? I've tried a few different things (`click` instead of `change`, etc), but it all comes back to the fact that when clicking on the text, `this` is not the element i clicked on, and I can't seem to get past that.

Comment: What is it that you expect `this` to refer to? jQuery arranges for `this` to refer to the element involved in the event.

Comment: Also you need to post that "disabling code" because that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: Without seeing your "change" handler code, nobody can help.

Comment: @Pointy I'm expecting `this` to refer to the element I click on. But if I create 3 sets and click on the text in the third one, it refers to the first one, even before it hits the disabling code, it's already in the wrong block if I have `debugger` as the first line in the "change" handler code.

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: How about `$('.form-element').on('change')` - this way you can query inside that particular form element and there will be no confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike most languages, `this` in javascript usually refers to the parent calling object, which can be almost anything depending on the context.

Long story shory, try wrapping `this` in the jQuery selector like so:

```
$('.form').on('change', '.foo-bool-field-form-toggle', function(e) {
  // disabling code goes here
  $(this).whatever
});
```

Basically, `$(this)` will refer to the DOM element which triggered the callback event (i.e. `change`), and will work for `click` or any other event trigger.